# How to disable/remap app shortcuts in Microsoft RDP Client (Mac to Windows)

Tags: windows, mac, remote-desktop

I connect to Windows 7 from OSX Yosemite using Microsoft Remote Desktop. In windows we have the following mappings:

<kbd>Start</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> = Run first application in the task bar

<kbd>Start</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> = Run second application in the task bar

etc. until <kbd>Start</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> for the tenth.

Unfortunately, the Microsoft Remote Desktop (v8.0.32) application I have running on my Mac has <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> mapped to Full Screen. I would like to remove this local mapping so that these key chords are passed through to the remote machine.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround for this is to issue the following key chords instead:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

This is because the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is not picked up by Microsoft Remote Desktop running on the Mac, but it is still picked up by Windows.

Comment: Solves the problem but doesn't quite answer the qn...